# Input of SAR logic

Tags: adc

Do we need to add the vpulse,maybe 1 or 0,to the reset of SAR logic?I think we have to feed a vpulse to reset,but after i saw lots of simulation waveform,i begin wondering my thinking ,because i don't see any reset waveform shown in the simulation.

I mean:Are the SAR logic's input comparator,reset,and clock,or just comparator and clock?

Comment: Output needs internal shift register states to count bits and determine when data is ready and delayed pulses to latch each compare result, after each clock active edge. but no other inputs.

Answer (score 0):

The SAR state-machine needs to know when to start the next conversion, thus RESET is a fine name for that state. That state might as well result in the MSB being ON, to be optionally toggled off depending upon comparator 1/0 state.

Upon optionally toggling the MSB off, the MSB-1 is automatically set ON; the next clock pulse may toggle MSB-1 off, but must set MSB-2 ON.

Comment: i don't understand about the meaning of fine name you said